sum sets are equal
I have two sequence of positive integers say $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6$ (they may be repeated) such that the multisets $\{a_1, a_1+a_2, \cdots , a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_6, a_6, a_6+a_5, \cdots ,a_6+a_5+\cdots +a_1\}=\{b_1, b_1+b_2, \cdots , b_1+b_2+\cdots +b_6, b_6, b_6+b_5, \cdots ,b_6+b_5+\cdots +b_1\}$.
This means that the multiset containing all consecutive partial sums involving $a_1$ and $a_6$ is equal to the multiset containing all consecutive partial sums involving $b_1$ and $b_6$.
From here can we say that either $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$ or $a_i=b_{7-i}$ for all $i$ ? I have tried with some particular examples and it worked.

Positivity is the key here.  Smallest is $a_1$ on the left and $b_1$ on the right,  so these match,  and so on.

No, $a_1$ can be $b_5+b_6$ for example.

Oh, I thought the terms were nested, but they aren't.  So,  right.  Can't order them the way I said.

So, what are the terms? Every possible subset sum?

No, just all consecutive sums involving $a_1$ and $a_6$. (Similarly $b_1$ and $b_6$).

Why $6$? Have you tried for different length sequences?

In general, it should be true. Lesser than length 6 sequences can be handled easily.

Well, the smallest number in the sums have to be either $a_1$ or $a_6$ and $b_1$ or $b_6$ so wolog we can assume it is $a_1=b_1$.  Then the second is either $a_1+a_2$ or $a_6$ of $b_1+b_2$ or $b_6$ and if we want the sequences to differ suppose $b_6 = a_1+a_2$.  Can we continue?  I actually don't see that it need be true but I too lazy to try to figure it out or to try to think of any ways to systematize it rather the scatter shot.

It's false:
$$a_i = 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2 \quad b_i = 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3 $$
Set of partial sums for $a_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 $$
Set of partial sums for $b_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10 $$

Edit:
This is not true even for 5 elements...
$$a_i = 1, 2, 1, 1,  2 \quad b_i = 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 $$
Set of partial sums for $a_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 $$
Set of partial sums for $b_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 $$

Edit2:
This is not true even for 4 elements...
$$a_i = 1, 2, 1, 2 \quad b_i = 1, 1, 1, 3 $$
Set of partial sums for $a_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6 $$
Set of partial sums for $b_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6 $$

Edit3:
This is not true even for 3 elements...
$$a_i = 1, 2, 2 \quad b_i = 1, 1, 3 $$
Set of partial sums for $a_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 5 $$
Set of partial sums for $b_i$ in order is
$$ 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5 $$

On the bright side, it is true for 2 elements
